# How to boostrap a model with fixed and random effect in R (unknown underling distribution)?

Tags: r, glm, mixed-models, confidence-interval

Sample dataset

```
df <- data.frame (species = rep(c("A","B","C","D"), times = 20),
                  factor = rep(c("1","2","3","4"), each = 10), 
                  yaxis <- c(-31.71,   3.04,   2.24 , 86.67,   1.49 ,  1.08,   1.90,   1.29,   1.24 ,  2.21 ,  3.01,   2.41  , 6.35 ,  -114.15 , 41.23   ,3.11 ,  1.16  , 0.67 , -5.70  , 0.87 ,  3.87 , -61.49 ,  2.41 ,  1.66 ,  3.65 ,  2.42 ,  3.06  , 1.32, 2.03,   0.75 ,  3.16,   1.90 ,  4.77 ,  0.10,   3.71 , -1.18 ,  4.69 , 11.46 , 10.77  , 0.61 ,-26.54 , -0.21 , 47.89 ,  1.42 -12.07  , 4.08  , 6.80 ,  3.67  , 3.75 ,  9.13  , 4.57 ,  2.67 ,  0.02 ,  1.96 , -1.04  -0.61, 2.44 , -0.79  , 2.20  , 1.16  ,12.53 ,  0.72   ,4.00 ,  2.89  , 2.10 ,16.54  , 8.50  , 1.66 ,-15.02  ,-0.21  ,-5.29 , 3.12  ,-1.77  ,14.01   ,2.25 ,  6.41  , 7.21   ,7.92 , 11.46  , 9.33,   0.03  , 3.43))
```

I want to test the model

```
Model : yaxis ~ species + (1|factor), data = df
```

The underlying distribution: Not clear (It is an index that has positive and negative values, not bounded). I want to bootstrap the data and estimate the means and confidence intervals. How can I do this?

I cobbled togther a couple of answers and tried the following. I get `Error in statistic(data, original, ...) :  could not find function "statistic"`

```
library(boot)
my.function = y ~ x
sp <- split(df, df$species)
y <- lapply(sp, function(x){
  avg <- mean(df$yaxis)
  basic <- boot.ci(boot(x, my.function, R = 1000), type = "basic")$basic
  CI.LL <- basic[4]
  CI.UL <- basic[5]
  data.frame(avg, CI.LL, CI.UL)
})

do.call(rbind, y)
```